# creating arrays of objects that store arrays attributes

Tags: c++, arrays, object, inheritance

Shape.h

```
class Shape {

private:
string name;

public:
Shape(name);
string getName();
void setName(string);
};
```

Triangle.h

```
class Triangle: public Shape {

private:
int x;
int y;

public:
Triangle(name,int[3],int[3]);
int getX();
int getY();
void setX(int);
void setY(int);
};
```

Triangle.cpp

```
Triangle::Triangle(string name,int _x[],int_y[]):Shape(name) {
x[] = _x[];
y[] = _y[];

}

int Square::getX() {
return x
}

int Square::getY() {
return y;
}

void Square::setX(int _x) {
x = _x;
}

void Square::setY(int _y) {
y = _y;
}
```

i need to create triangle that takes in name and 3 points of (x,y). when i try to create an array of triangle on the main `Triangle Tri[50]`; i got the following errors

```
Triangle::Triangle(std::string,int*,int*)
candidates expects 3 arguments, 0 provided
Triangle::Triangle(const Triangle&)
candidates expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

can pls help me check what is wrong with my constructor?? is it because i am creating an array of objects that store arrays of x and y? so i need to use references and pointers for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create

```
Triangle Tri[50];
```

it will try to call the `default constructor` to initialize those elements in your `Tri` array, however, you did not provide such a `default constructor` and you did not call the constructor with 3 parameters, therefore, compiler complains.

Meanwhile, you seems to try to directly initialize one array with another inside the constructor of `Triangle`:

```
Triangle::Triangle(string name,int _x[],int_y[]):Shape(name) {
   x[] = _x[];//^^I don't understand how this will work in practice.
   y[] = _y[];
}
```

There is no direct assignment on arrays in C++, though C++ `std::array` (since C++11) has `overloaded operator=`, but this is not true for regular array.